# MySQL 5.7 force to use/create MyISAM

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam

with respect to documentation where is no possibility to turn off InnoDB storage engine since MySQL 5.7.5 , and InnoDB is default engine .

But how I can  use MyISAM  engine ? --innodb=OFF or --skip-innodb not work since 5.7.5.

Will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/myisam-storage-engine.html), you need to specify storage engine while creating a table, e.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE t (i INT) ENGINE = MYISAM;
```